# Как понять, что падает при нагрузочном тестировании?

Tags: node.js, nginx

Провожу нагрузочное тестирование сервиса на NodeJS, запросы к которому проксируются  через Nginx. Скорость загрузки страниц растёт линейно до тех пор, пока не начинает вываливаться в Timeout.

[image: Линейный график времени ответа на запросы]

На стороне NodeJS все данные закэшированы в Redis и ответ генерируется в пределах 50мс. Как определить, что именно падает и начинает тормозить - nginx или NodeJS?

Comment: В 99.9% случаях тормозит не nginx. Что именно тормозит у вас в приложении, надо смотреть

Comment: Ещё я однажды день потратил на поиск проблем в приложении и nginx, пока не понял, что на самом деле упёрся в пропускную способность сети.

Comment: Кстати, в свете вашего следующего вопроса, `JSON.stringify` это очень тяжёлая и синхронная блокирующая операция, особенно для больших объектов. Так что возможно причина в этом.